# Java :: JacksonXmlProperty :: Multiple fields with same name

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm extending code from an existing Java class that serializes to and from XML. The existing class is somewhat like this:

```
@Getter
@JacksonXmlRootElement("element")
public class Element {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "type", isAttribute = true)
    private String type;

}
```

The `type` field has a finite set of possible values so I created an enum `Type` with all possible values and (to avoid breaking existing functionality) added a new field to the class, like so:

```
@Getter
@JacksonXmlRootElement("element")
public class Element {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "type", isAttribute = true)
    private String type;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "type", isAttribute = true)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = TypeDeserializer.class)
    private Type typeEnum;

}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Multiple fields representing property "type": Element#type vs Element#typeEnum
```

I understand why this is a problem cuz when Jackson would try to serialize the class, two fields in my class map onto the same field in the output XML.

I tried adding a `@JsonIgnore` on one of the fields and it gets rid of the error but has the side effect of not populating the ignored field either. Is there a way to annotate that a field should be deserialized (while reading XML) but not serialized (while writing XML)?

I really need to keep both fields in the class to not disturb any legacy code that might be using the first field, but at the same time allow newer code to leverage the second field.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you still need the `String type` field? Note that it is private, so you can easily refactor this class to stop using it. If the values are truly a finite set of possibilities, then you can derive the string from `typeEnum`'s value. You could add a field/method to the `Type` enum to return the exact canonical string you like.

Comment: The field has an automatic getter, thanks to the `@Getter` lombok annotation on the class..

Comment: When removing the `type` field, you would re-implement the `getType()` method with your own logic in order to uphold the same external interface.